# Put a tabbar across the top in a metro app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, tabcontrol, winrt-xaml

I want to make a WinRT Metro app that has similar functionality to this:

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html#Inbox

How does a tab bar with links to each of the various pages of the application fit into a Metro-styled app? Would you use the AppBar? On the top or the left? Would you use a radio button for each page? Would you use a FlipView to change pages? What examples exist for this type of metro app?

Comment: And why does Google translate "winrt" into "winter"?

Comment: Because it's not a word, and the closest word (per its translator) is winter. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case you could just do the same thing only with less chrome (gradients/dropshadows). The buttons could just be RadioButtons with Style="{StaticResource TextRadioButtonStyle}". The tabs would just change the filter - based on selected tab your view model would provide different ItemsSource for the list.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get your app into the Windows 8 store (of course it is!) I recommend that you dig into the Metro UX guidelines. The guidelines for navigation are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500.aspx). It documents several navigation patterns.

If you do choose to use an AppBar as your navigation control, you can pin an AppBar to the top of your XAML/C# app using this snippet.The AppBar will be open upon displaying the page because IsOpen  is set to true and uses IsSticky to stay open.

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="SampleNavBar" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
       [PUT YOUR NAV CONTROLS HERE]            
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

For an example that is close to what you are looking for use the weather app that comes with Windows 8 and go to the Locations screen. Right click or swipe to bring up the app bar. The app displays both a top AppBar and a bottom AppBar. The top AppBar is a navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the example suggestion.